# Encoding vb.net to utf-8

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-encode

Hy guys, I recive this String `Attivit&#224;` and it could be  `Attività` . I take It from  `gridViewID.Rows(y).Cells(0).Text`. How do I encode it?

Comment: You don't. .NET strings are already Unicode. Your own question proved this when you posted `Attività`.  This page is Unicode. SO is a .NET web app. What you posted isn't Unicode, it's the HTML encoding of `à`. This didn't have to be encoded in the first place. You can type `à` in this page as I just did, or even non-Latin text like `Αυτό Εδώ` without any kind of encoding.

Comment: How did this string end up in the grid? .NET doesn't do this, it doesn't have to. Either the application itself encoded the string or the source data was HTML-encoded. That's what you need to fix - either remove the code that performs the HTML encoding, or *de*code the source data using eg [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=net-6.0) or [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This String end up in the grid with `gridViewID.DataSource = dt ' is DataTable` and `gridViewID.DataBind()`

Comment: Where does the data for that DataTable come from? A database? Was that database table supposed to contain HTML encoded strings? All databases support Unicode one way or another. You could either *not* use HTML encoding to begin with, or you'll have to decode the strings in the DataTable before displaying them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.